# Is this some kind of trick question? Submanifold "proof"

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dim Riemmanian Manifold (actually only the differentiable part is necessary for this problem) and $f$ is a continuous differentiable function $f: M \to \Bbb{R}$  meaning the derivatives of $f$ are smooth (and hence continuous). Suppose $p \in M$, and $f(p) = k$ prove that $f^{-1}(k)$ (i.e, the level set), is a $n-1$-dim smooth sub manifold of $M$ in a neighbourhood of $p$. In addition, you may assume $grad(f(p)) \neq  0$.

Doesn't this just fall straight out of the definition because $df$ has constant rank of $1$…and therefore is an $n-1$-dim sub manifold

I should mention that I know the theorem off hand, but the one in the book requires charts, in the following sense.

> THe subset $W^k \subset M^n$ of a smooth manifold is a smooth sub manifold if $\forall x \in W$, $\exists h: U \to U'$ on $M$ such that $x \in U$ and $h(U \cap W) = U' \cap \Bbb R^k$ where $\Bbb R^k \subset R^n$ is the standard subspace.

Comment: What is your definition of submanifold? This is indeed a simple exercise once you have stated the correct calculus theorem.

Comment: What in the setup guarantees $df$ has constant rank $1$ (i.e. no critical points)?

Comment: @SamLisi, let's see I found this in a book, but the theorem I know of hand. I think the book's definition require a chart.

Comment: @Neal, I forget to add that the gradient is nonzero.

Comment: Do you know that a fiber of a submersion is a manifold? It's just the local form of submersions and it can be proved using inverse function theorem.

Comment: @user40276, I have to look that up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Since you know the relevant theorem,* consult it. Properly interpreted, its conclusion hands you the submanifold charts on a platter.

---

The relevant theorem is

> the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Well I am not sure how to relate the definition I have to what I know. The greyed definition requires the existence of a chart, actually I get this too in the proof of the rank theorem, perhaps they coincide?

Comment: The relevant theorem is not the rank theorem! The rank theorem shows up in the proof of the relevant theorem, but is about linear operators on finite-dimensional vector spaces, not smooth functions on manifolds.

Comment: So from what I am reading off from wikipedia, it looks like the chart given in the greyed is by the last coordinate of $p$. I don't know if I am too off. But this is supposed to be really straightforward...

Comment: @jip It is straightforward. You just have to parse the statement of the theorem and apply it.

Comment: I got a question. Isn't the Implicit Function Theorem defined for a map going form Euclidean space to Euclidean space? My map is going from a manifold $M$ to $\Bbb R$

Comment: @jip Precompose with a local coordinate map.

Comment: I am guessing you mean for a chart $g: N \to M$ with $N \subset \Bbb R^n$, we apply the theorem to $f\circ g$?